# Is camera calibration dependent on image resolution?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I am trying to calibrate a camera which is 10M pixel. Should I do it in full resolution, or can I do it in, say, half resolution?

I am sure that if I reduce the resolution, the accuracy of parameters would be reduced, but are the parameters that I can calculate (K and D ) related to resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Calibrate at the resolution that you will run at. If you plan on running at 1/2 resolution, calibrate at that.

The distortion is mostly a function of the imaging system ( lens ). The chip is still reading from the same image plane and area at 5M as it is at 10M.